# copy multiple directories in multiple directories without loop

Tags: xargs, file-copy

I want to copy directories from one variable to directories from another one but without loop.

```
from="fromdir1 fromdir2"
to="todir1 todir2"
```

I mean `fromdir1` to `todir1`, `fromdir2` to `todir2`.

I think it can be done with `xargs` but I don't know how.

Comment: Hi. You've not completely stated what you want: do you want to copy **each** directory from `from` to **each** directory in `to`, or do you just want to copy the first entry of `from` to the first entry of `to`, the second entry of `from`  to the second entry of `to` and so on?

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the correction. I edited the post. I meant `fromdir1` to `todir1` and `fromdir2` to `todir2`

Comment: But then xargs is the wrong tool and you already have gotten a solution in a previous question of yours. You need a loop, and it goes like this:

Comment: my question was **without** loop

Comment: yes, I know, but that can't work. `xargs` doesn't do what you say you *think* it does, so the answer you've already gotten is the best you can get.

Comment: yeah, I got it, but it was just an assumption, so the `parallel` solution below is appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GNU `parallel` with linked arguments:

```
parallel --link cp {1} {2} ::: from1 from2 from3 ::: to1 to2 to3
```

If the `from` and `to`-files are in respectives text lists, use

```
parallel --link cp {1} {2} :::: fromlist :::: tolist
```

note the 4 colons vs. 3 colons previously. More info on GNU parallel on the [website](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel.html).

For reading them from `bash` array variables, this will do:

```
parallel --link cp {1} {2} ::: "${from[@]}" ::: "${to[@]}"
```